# How can I create an email account whose access depends always on three people?

Tags: passwords

I have two collegues, and we have the objective of creating an email account with a password composed of three pieces, each piece known only by one of us. We live in three different places, very far away from each other. How can we do this?

I thought about one of them have remote desktop control on the other, and this one on mine, then each one of them type a few characters in the password field on the account creation process. But this presents two problems:

- How do they know there is no keylogger in my computer on in the second one computer?
- Which software can be used to do this?

Is there any better approach, or service, which allows to create e-mail accounts, whose access can only be done if each one writes remotely its part of the password?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that require some python at least IMHO.

Basically you can achieve this by setting a remote server that waits for N connections to be done (you can do a basic user/password login for this), then once all required users are connected you can create an account on some webmail server that has his own exposed API (i guess gmail has it's own)

the main point is that if you 3 are sharing a key and you don't want other login without your permission, no one should own that host and no one should ever join in, because the owner could change the code and save some sensible data.

but i think there is some nasty point after that: how could you set the phone number of that account on the convalidation?

you could also activate account security if webmail server has it but that require that you have that account on your mobile phone and this doesn't prevent access without permission

-----
EDIT: if you want just to remote type in the password, you could use TeamViewer too, i think it's keylogger proof and you can use Avast virtual keyboard to be much more safer

Comment: The server + clients + api call option is not bad, however it would require development, them to trust my code, and would still present a problem for login together. The teamviewer option is not bad, if it's really keylogger proof.

Comment: what kind of problem do you expect for connecting you all togheder? and for the code you can do a live session while reading the code and deploying online